# Как в телеграмм выводить кнопки из списка по 10 штук?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Хотя для профессионала это легко, я вот вообще туплю((
Есть вот такой код:

```
answers = [Как бороться с детским «купи!»?
           Пока все дома: способы бережного взаимодействия
           Стыд как инструмент воспитания
           Как справиться с подростком в самоизоляции?
           Как родителям реагировать на критику детей
           Как уберечь от беды доверчивых и искренних подростков?
           Как отцу реагировать на поклонников дочери-подростка?
           Как быть спокойным родителем?
           Делая ребенка счастливым сейчас, мы лишаем его счастья в будущем
           Фразы, которые обижают детей
           Многодетность — это не страшно. О фобиях и предрассудках
           "Людмила Петрановская о карантине: «Совместный опыт преодоления трудностей 
           сближает»"
           Как воспитать здоровое поколение в нездоровых условиях
           Почему дети испытывают нас на прочность?
           Как и зачем говорить с детьми о коронавирусе: советы для всех возрастов]
            
#Создаем клавиатуру и каждую из кнопок (по 1 в ряд)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="Секундочку!⏲ Готовлю для Вас список статей!")
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
            js_btns = []
            for i, a in enumerate(answers):
                n = str(i+2)
                js_btns.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=a, callback_data=n))          
            back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='d1')
            keyboard.add(*js_btns, back)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="✅Готово!✅ \n\nВот что есть почитать:", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

не могу понять( как сделать, чтобы кнопки выводились по 10 штук из списка, чтобы можно было нажать вперёд и текущие кнопки заменились следующими 10ю новыми с другими названиями статей (т.е. листание по списку)???Помогите пожалуйста!!!!

Comment: У вас этот код запускается?

Comment: Это всего лишь часть. А вообще код работает.